# ASP.NET MVC EF Code First restrict access to user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework and Code First approach. I just wanted to ask if there are better ways to handle this implementation of user restriction than I have made?

Im making a Portal that customers can use to view data related to them. This is based on ASP.NET Identity. So on every controller I do this to get the current user:

```
var user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

And then I add this to the query for context:

```
//Query the context and get all stuff from this users companies.
var restaurants = from p in db.Restaurants orderby p.Name where p.CompanyId == user.CompanyId select p;

var all= restaurants.ToListAsync();

return View(await all);
```

Is this a normal implementation, or is there a better way than putting this on each controller action?

Comment: This belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MarkC. first, that's not an allowed close reason. [Migration is allowed though](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254080/can-we-move-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-codereview-se). Second, there's not much  to review here. That's not bad, just it will make it harder to answer.

Comment: Before posting on Code Review, read the [on-topic help centre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first.

Comment: @Riker Fair enough - but why does the site have standards if we're just going to go by the length of the question? If it doesn't adhere to the standards but it's short we'll just let it pass?

Comment: It's a bit of a judgement call either way, honestly. As it's currently worded, I can see an argument for migrating to Code Review. However, if the question instead was simply, "How do I restrict access by user?", then it's perfectly on-topic.

Comment: I thought it would get better replies if I added what I already have tried. But yes, the question is how do I restrict a users access to data only applicable to them through Code First and ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 1):

Well, normal enough, I suppose. However, this isn't actually restricting by user, but rather by company that the user belongs to. That's fine if that's what you intended, but just be aware that any user that belongs to that same company also has access.

If you do want to restrict by just user, you'd need a foreign key to the user on the object. At which point, you'd handle the query in the same way, only filtering by the the user id, rather than the company id. You also wouldn't need to actually get the user object at that point, since you'd have all the info you needed from `User.Identity.GetUserId()`.

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var restaurants = from p in db.Restaurants orderby p.Name where p.UserId == userId select p;
```

Note: you need to actually save the user id to a variable first, because the method `User.Identity.GetUserId()` is not translatable to SQL. It's a minor point, but you'll get an exception if you try to use that in your query directly.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have  used something like a model binder to translate my principal object such as:

```
public class IPrincipalModelBinder: IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        if (bindingContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");
        IPrincipal user = controllerContext.HttpContext.User;
        return user;
    }
}
```

and then you could have your actions like:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult ActionName(IPrincipal loggedInUser)
    {
        var user = // get from repository
        // do stuff
        return View();
    }
```

and you register your ModelBinder in the `Global.asax` in `Application_Start`

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(IPrincipal)] = new IPrincipalModelBinder();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the security function based on manager role is much more practical, you say the user's permission and he only accesses the controllers he's allowed. See the example below:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Restaurants")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Do stuff here

    return View();
}
```

In this method for example, you will only be able to access the users who have the role of Restaurants

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1102/aspnet-mvc-role-based-security

Comment: Link-only answers aren't that helpful. Can you summarise, along with providing a link?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Say that I add all users to the Restaurant-role. I still need to get the current users CompanyID to be able to get that accounts rescources?